# How to connect Dialogflow webhook to Flask application using ngrok in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, dialogflow-es, ngrok

I am working on a cooking cuisine chat bot and have created some intents in Dialogflow. I want to connect my Python code to it so that it can parse user input and determine which cuisine and type of food (main dish, dessert, snack, drink, etc.) the user wants. Then, it should show a random recipe from that type and cuisine.

I am using Jupyter Notebook for coding and ngrok to establish the connection between the Flask application and Dialogflow. However, I am facing some issues with the connection.

Can someone guide me through the process of connecting Dialogflow to Python code for this chat bot? I have checked the path of my credentials file and Excel file, and both are okay.

Here's my source code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from google.cloud import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
from google.cloud.dialogflow_v2 import types
from flask import Flask, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set environment variable for the Google Cloud credentials file
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/home/papri/Desktop/Final project/Flask/chatxyz.json"

#@app.route('/')
#def index():
    #return 'Hello, world!'

# Create a route to handle incoming requests from Dialogflow
@app.route('/webhook',methods=['POST'])
def webhook():

    # Parse the request JSON from Dialogflow
    req = request.get_json(force=True)
    
    # Extract the user input text, cuisine entity, and recipe type entity from the request JSON
    text = req['queryResult']['queryText']
    cuisine_entity = req['queryResult']['parameters'].get('cuisine_entity', {}).get('stringValue')
    food_type_entity = req['queryResult']['parameters'].get('food_type_entity', {}).get('stringValue')
    
    # Read the Excel sheet into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel('/home/papri/Desktop/Final project/recipes.xlsx')
    
    # Filter the DataFrame to only include rows that match the cuisine and recipe type
    filtered_df = df[(df['Cuisine'] == cuisine_entity) & (df['Type'] == food_type_entity)]
    
    # Check if any rows were found
    if len(filtered_df) > 0:
        # Select a random row from the filtered DataFrame
        random_row = filtered_df.sample()
        
        # Construct the response JSON for Dialogflow
        response = {
            'fulfillmentMessages': [
                {
                    'text': {
                        'text': [
                            f"Name: {random_row.iloc[0]['Name']}\n\nIngredients: {random_row.iloc[0]['Ingredients']}\n\nRecipe: {random_row.iloc[0]['Recipe']}"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    else:
        # Construct the response JSON for Dialogflow
        response = {
            'fulfillmentMessages': [
                {
                    'text': {
                        'text': [
                            "No recipes found for the given cuisine and type."
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    
    # Return the response JSON to Dialogflow
    return response
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I run the Flask app, it provides me with a URL that says:

"Not Found.
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually, please check your spelling and try again."

To test, I added the following lines of code to my app:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'
```

And when I run the app, it then shows "Hello, world!".

This is the raw API response from Dialogflow while testing the bot:

```
{
  "responseId": "7748a390-b396-4e2e-ac98-72c1e51a7229-470ed8da",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "Indian dessert",
    "parameters": {
      "food_type_entity": "Dessert",
      "cuisine_entity": "Indian"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/chatagnt-jolj/agent/intents/92d12a5d-b65e-42ab-af00-05673c429a15",
      "displayName": "cuisine.type"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 594
    },
    "languageCode": "en",
    "sentimentAnalysisResult": {
      "queryTextSentiment": {
        "score": 0.1,
        "magnitude": 0.1
      }
    }
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE, State: URL_UNREACHABLE, Reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx, HTTP status code: 500."
  }
}
```